# BaseAdapter not working properly with OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I  have a listView with 8 items. Every item contain a Single Button. I want that when each item of list clicked the background of that item changes. I use baseAdapter and all things are correct except when the first item (zero position) is clicked, then the background is not changing. This is my adapter:

```
class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    ViewHolder viewHolder ;
    int SelectedItem = 55 ;// dummy integer
    Button[] buttons = new Button[8];

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MainListTitle.size();// array of string
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view==null){
            // inflate the layout
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_list_item, viewGroup ,false);
            // well set up the ViewHolde
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.Title = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mainListButton);
            viewHolder.Title.setText(MainListTitle.get(i));
            viewHolder.Title.setId(i);
            buttons[i]=viewHolder.Title ;
            viewHolder.Title.setOnClickListener(this);

            //store the holder with the view.
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),view.getId()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (view.getId()){

                case 0:
                    onButtonSelcted(0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    onButtonSelcted(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    onButtonSelcted(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    onButtonSelcted(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    onButtonSelcted(4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    onButtonSelcted(5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    onButtonSelcted(6);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    onButtonSelcted(7);
                    break;
            }
    }


     class ViewHolder{
        Button Title ;
        }

    private void onButtonSelcted(int position){
        if (SelectedItem == position){}
        else {
            buttons[position].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            if (SelectedItem != 55){
                buttons[SelectedItem].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_900));
            }
            SelectedItem = position ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the buttons inside ListView? Why are you creating - Button[] buttons = new Button[8];?
Add R.layout.main_list_item to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a positive number ( so bigger than zero) with the setId() as the documentation states:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29

You might

```
...
viewHolder.Title.setId(i + 1);
...
```

and then

```
...
switch (view.getId() - 1){
...
```